# Como capturar string entre colchetes

Tags: java, regex

Preciso capturar strings entre colchetes dentro de uma string. Achei uma solução que não resolve meu problema totalmente: `\\[(.*?)\\]`

Uso assim:

```
Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(stringlToVerify);

if(mat.find()) {
   // Faz o que quero
}
```

Desse modo, se eu executar o regex com: `'ol[a' + 'm]undo'`

Ele vai pegar: `[a' + 'm]`

Mas nesse caso não é para pegar, pois as as duas strings estão sendo concatenadas, então não faz sentido.

Exemplo do que preciso:

```
  Entrada             Captura

1 + [aa]                  [aa]
[bb] + 2                  [bb]
'a' + [cc]                [cc]
['ola' + 'mundo']      ['ola' + 'mundo']
'[a' + 'b]'            
'[' + ']'        

[]                        []   (ou nada, também serve)
'Ola [world] legal'         
Oi ['[aa]'] ola           '[aa]'
```

No último caso, se não for possível fazer de maneira simples, não tem problema. Fiz um método que remove todas as strings entre aspas simples.

Comment: Olá Eduardo, digamos, uma entrada válida seria uma string que obrigatoriamente está entre aspas e entre colchetes? Por exemplo: 'ola [querido] mundo', onde a palavre "querido" seria capturada? Se possível tente detalhar mais seus requisitos. Expressões regulares muito complexas pode atrapalhar ao invés de ajudar.

Comment: @Eduardo E o que deve capturar com este texto: `['aa']`?

Comment: @RenatoColaço, se fosse testada a string 'ola [querido] mundo', o retorno deve ser vazio. Atualizei a liste de entradas e saídas na minha pergunta adicionando esse cenário. Obrigado.

Comment: @Mariano, se for entrada a string ['aa'] o retorno deverá ser 'aa' ou ['aa'], tanto faz, o importante é capturar o que estiver entre parêntesis.

Comment: @EduardoH.M.Garcia Pode haver aspas com escapes? (`'a \'b\' [c] d' [e]`)

Comment: O último caso é inconsistente. Deveria ser `['[aa]']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Expressão regular:

```
\G[^\[']*(?:'[^']*'[^\['*]*)*(\[[^]']*(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*\])
```

#### Código:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "\\G"                    // Início do texto ou fim do casamento anterior
                   + "[^\\[']*"               // Texto sem colchetes nem aspas simples
                   + "(?:'[^']*'[^\\['*]*)*"  // Opcional: Texto em aspas + texto sem "[" nem "'"
                   + "(\\["                   // Grupo 1: Colchete de abertura
                   +     "[^]']*"             //        + texto sem "]" nem "'"
                   +     "(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*" //        + texto em aspas + texto sem "]" nem "'"
                   + "\\])";                  //        + colchete de fechamento
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher mat;

final String[] entrada = {
    "1 + [aa]",
    "[bb] + 2",
    "'a' + [cc]",
    "['ola' + 'mundo']",
    "'[a' + 'b]'",
    "'[' + ']'",
    "[]",
    "'Ola [world] legal'",
    "Oi ['[aa]'] ola"
};

//Loop cada string na entrada
for (String stringlToVerify :  entrada) {
    mat = pat.matcher(stringlToVerify);
    System.out.println("\nEntrada: " + stringlToVerify);

    if (mat.find())
        do { // Loop cada texto entre colchetes casado
            System.out.println("Captura: " + mat.group(1));
        } while (mat.find());
    else
        System.out.println("Não há colchetes fora das aspas");
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Entrada: 1 + [aa]
Captura: [aa]

Entrada: [bb] + 2
Captura: [bb]

Entrada: 'a' + [cc]
Captura: [cc]

Entrada: ['ola' + 'mundo']
Captura: ['ola' + 'mundo']

Entrada: '[a' + 'b]'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: '[' + ']'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: []
Captura: []

Entrada: 'Ola [world] legal'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: Oi ['[aa]'] ola
Captura: ['[aa]']
```

Pode testar aqui:
http://ideone.com/6ZSzSz

#### Descrição:

```
\G[^\[']*(?:'[^']*'[^\['*]*)*(\[[^]']*(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*\])
```

- `\G` - [Âncora](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/barra-letra.html#3_4) (ou asserção atômica) que casa o começo da cadeia de caracteres ou fim do casamento anterior (*[continuing at the end of the previous match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)*).

  Esta é a construção mais importante neste regex.
  É para garantir que cada tentativa de casamento começa apenas onde o motor parou no casamento anterior. Assim, um casamento não pode começar no meio do texto, evitando uma captura em, por exemplo:

  ```
  '....   [a' + 'b]  .....'
          ^       ^
          |- Aqui-|
  ```
- `[^\[']*` - [Lista](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html#2_1_2) que casa todos os caracteres que não são colchetes nem aspas simples.
- `(?:'[^']*'[^\['*]*)*` - Este é um [grupo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-fantasma.html#3_5_2) que é repetido 0 ou mais vezes, casando:

  - `'[^']*'` - Texto em aspas
  - `[^\['*]*` - seguido por mais caracteres que não são colchetes nem aspas.

  > Esta construção usa uma técnica conhecida como "[desenrolando o loop](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~sandro/cursos/mo615/slides/12-transformacoes_lacos.pdf)" (*[unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)*).

  ---

  *Até aqui, podemos casar todos os caracteres da string antes dos colchetes.*

  ---
- `(\[[^]']*(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*\])` - [Grupo de captura](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3) (*[capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)*) que permite [referenciar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) o texto casado (usando [`Matcher#group(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-)) com:

  - `\[` - colchete de abertura
  - `[^]']*` - mais caracteres que não são colchetes nem aspas
  - `(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*` - opcionalmente aspas dentro dos colchetes e mais caracteres que não são colchetes nem aspas (também *desenrolando o loop*)
  - `\]` -  colchete de fechamento.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu meu problema completamente. Consegui entender melhor regex com a sua descrição do código. Abraço.

Comment: Testei sua solução em mais alguns cenários, e houve falhas. Cenário com falha: Oi ['[aa'] ola    retorna ['[aa]

Comment: @Eduardo - Editei a resposta para seus novos requisitos.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pode me dizer como ficaria se adicionássemos aspas duplas no meio da coisa? Quero dizer, fazer o regex funcionar da mesma maneira que funciona agora, mas aplicar as mesmas regras para aspas duplas.

Answer (score 2):

## Não use regex

Embora seja possível (como já apontado em outras respostas), regex não parece ser a ferramenta correta para este problema. Não vou nem entrar no mérito da expressão ter ficado um "pequeno monstro", difícil de entender e de manter - basta ver na sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/544032/112052) <sup><sup><sub>que foi apagada</sub></sup></sup> a dificuldade que é para adicionar uma pequena modificação.

No seu caso, um *parser* parece ser mais adequado, já que você tem expressões que devem ser avaliadas (podendo ser números ou strings, que por sua vez podem ser operandos do operador `+`, que podem ou não estar dentro de colchetes, que também podem fazer parte de outra operação `+`, e os outros operandos podem ser strings ou números, ou estarem dentro de colchetes, etc).

Como há uma série de regras "especiais" (como colchetes dentro e fora das aspas, que tem que ser interpretados de forma diferente, etc), a regex acaba ficando realmente complicada, já que ela precisa de um monte de malabarismos para detectar em qual contexto está (se o `[` está ou não dentro das aspas, etc).

Já um *parser* cuida desta complexidade para você, dando também mais controle sobre cada parte da expressão sendo avaliada (sem contar a facilidade de manutenção, como veremos mais abaixo).

---

## Usando um *parser*

No caso, você pode usar um gerador de *parser*, por exemplo. Para a resposta abaixo, usarei o [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/).

Neste projeto também usei o [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), por facilitar alguns passos, e o JDK 8. A estrutura é bem simples:

```
ExpressionParser (diretório raiz do projeto)
 |
 |- pom.xml
 |
 |- src/main
         |
         |- java/expressionparser/main
         |     |
         |     |- Main.java
         |     |
         |     |- ExpressionEvaluator.java
         |
         |- antlr4/expressionparser
               |
               |- Expression.g4
```

No `pom.xml` adicionamos o Antlr nas dependências, e configuramos o respectivo *plugin* que fará o *build*:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>grupo.qualquer.mude.para.o.seu</groupId>
    <artifactId>expressionparser</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>expressionparser</name>
    <properties>
        <antlr4.version>4.3</antlr4.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <javac.target>1.8</javac.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr4.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${antlr4.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-visitor</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>expressionparser.main.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

Já no arquivo `Expression.g4` definimos a gramática das expressões que queremos fazer o *parsing*:

```
grammar Expression;

parse : expr;

expr
 : atom              #atomExpr
 | expr PLUS expr    #additiveExpr
 ;

atom
 : STRING               #stringAtom
 | INT                  #numberAtom
 | ID ( brackets ID )?  #idAtom
 | brackets             #parExpr
 ;

brackets : OPAR expr? CPAR;
STRING : '\'' (~['])* '\'' | '"' (~["])* '"';
PLUS : '+';
OPAR : '[';
CPAR : ']';
INT : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Basicamente definimos que uma expressão pode ser:

- números (`INT`, que está definido como um ou mais dígitos)
- strings (`STRING`, zero ou mais caracteres entre aspas `''` ou `""`)
- identificadores (`ID`, uma sequência de uma ou mais letras)

Além disso, expressões podem estar entre colchetes (`brackets`), podendo inclusive não ter nada entre eles (ou seja, pode ser apenas `[]`), e por fim também podemos ter expressões como operandos do operador `+` (definido por `PLUS`).

Tem também o caso de ter expressões "em sequência", sem um operador entre elas (como é o caso de `Oi ['[aa]'] ola`). Eu fiz uma definição bem específica (um identificador, seguido de expressão entre colchetes, seguido de outro identificador), pois não ficou claro quais são todas as possibilidades (não sei se poderia ter algo como `[a] [b] [c]`, por exemplo).

De qualquer forma, bastaria adaptar a gramática para aceitar tais casos. Para saber mais sobre como definir uma gramática, sugiro ler a documentação ([aqui](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexicon.md) e [aqui](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md)).

A princípio pode parecer mais complicado do que a regex, mas se você aprender ambas verá que na verdade esta é a solução mais adequada. E no final veremos como é mais simples modificá-la para adicionar um novo operador, por exemplo.

---

**Por enquanto não precisa criar os arquivos `Main.java` e `ExpressionEvaluator.java`**. Primeiro rode o Maven:

```
mvn clean install
```

Assim ele irá criar o diretório `target/generated-sources/antlr4/` na raiz do projeto, com várias classes geradas a partir da gramática que definimos acima:

```bash
$ find target/generated-sources/antlr4/
target/generated-sources/antlr4/
target/generated-sources/antlr4/Expression.tokens
target/generated-sources/antlr4/ExpressionLexer.tokens
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionLexer.java
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionBaseListener.java
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionBaseVisitor.java
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionParser.java
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionListener.java
target/generated-sources/antlr4/expressionparser/ExpressionVisitor.java
```

Se estiver usando uma IDE, veja como configurá-la para que as classes acima façam parte do *classpath* do seu projeto (no Netbeans, por exemplo, é automático, veja como é na sua).

A partir daí, podemos criar as nossas classes, que usam o *parser* e o *lexer* gerados acima.

Primeiro a classe `ExpressionEvaluator`:

```java
package expressionparser.main;

import expressionparser.ExpressionBaseVisitor;
import expressionparser.ExpressionParser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval;

public class ExpressionEvaluator extends ExpressionBaseVisitor<Void> {
    // lista com todas as expressões que têm colchetes
    private List<String> expressoesColchetes = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> getExpressoesColchetes() {
        return expressoesColchetes;
    }

    // ao encontrar uma expressão entre colchetes, adicionar na lista
    @Override
    public Void visitBrackets(ExpressionParser.BracketsContext ctx) {
        expressoesColchetes.add(getFullText(ctx));
        ExpressionParser.ExprContext expr = ctx.expr();
        // se tem algo dentro dos colchetes, continuar analisando
        return expr == null ? null : this.visit(expr);
    }

    // obter todo o texto do token, preservando os espaços originais
    private String getFullText(ParserRuleContext context) {
        if (context.start == null || context.stop == null || context.start.getStartIndex() < 0 || context.stop.getStopIndex() < 0) {
            return context.getText();
        }
        return context.start.getInputStream().getText(Interval.of(context.start.getStartIndex(), context.stop.getStopIndex()));
    }
}
```

No caso, eu apenas criei uma subclasse de `ExpressionBaseVisitor` (que é uma classe que "visita" todos os tokens da expressão sendo analisada).

No arquivo de gramática tem a linha `brackets : OPAR expr? CPAR;` para definir uma expressão entre colchetes, então o Antlr gerou o método `visitBrackets`, que é chamado sempre que tal expressão é encontrada. Neste caso, eu adiciono o texto dela na lista `expressoesColchetes` (tive que fazer um pequeno "malabarismo" para que ele pegue o texto com os espaços originais, pois apenas `getText()` pode removê-los caso haja uma expressão mais complexa dentro dos colchetes).

Depois, no arquivo `Main.java`, basta usar o `ExpressionEvaluator` para obter os colchetes:

```java
package expressionparser.main;

import expressionparser.ExpressionLexer;
import expressionparser.ExpressionParser;
import java.util.List;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] entrada = {
            "1 + [aa]",
            "[bb] + 2",
            "'a' + [cc]",
            "['ola' + 'mundo']",
            "'[a' + 'b]'",
            "'[' + ']'",
            "[]",
            "'Ola [world] legal'",
            "Oi ['[aa]'] ola",
            "[aa] + 42 + ['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def'] + xyz]"
        };
        for (String stringToVerify : entrada) {
            parse(stringToVerify);
        }
    }

    static void parse(String expressao) {
        ExpressionLexer lexer = new ExpressionLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(expressao));
        ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.parse();
        ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluator();
        evaluator.visit(tree);
        System.out.printf("\nEntrada: %s\n", expressao);
        // obtém a lista de expressões entre colchetes
        List<String> expressoesColchetes = evaluator.getExpressoesColchetes();
        if (expressoesColchetes.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Não há colchetes fora das aspas");
        } else {
            // mostra todas as capturas, separadas por |
            System.out.printf("Captura: %s\n", String.join("  |  ", expressoesColchetes));
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, eu uso o `ExpressionEvaluator` para obter todas as expressões entre colchetes.

Você pode rodar com o próprio Maven se quiser (`mvn exec:java`). A saída é:

```
Entrada: 1 + [aa]
Captura: [aa]

Entrada: [bb] + 2
Captura: [bb]

Entrada: 'a' + [cc]
Captura: [cc]

Entrada: ['ola' + 'mundo']
Captura: ['ola' + 'mundo']

Entrada: '[a' + 'b]'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: '[' + ']'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: []
Captura: []

Entrada: 'Ola [world] legal'
Não há colchetes fora das aspas

Entrada: Oi ['[aa]'] ola
Captura: ['[aa]']

Entrada: [aa] + 42 + ['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def'] + xyz]
Captura: [aa]  |  ['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def'] + xyz]  |  [abc + 'def']
```

Quando há mais de uma expressão, eu retorno todas na mesma linha (mas você poderia retornar uma por linha, tanto faz; uma vez tendo a lista, formate a saída da forma que achar melhor).

Repare no último caso, em que há uma expressão entre colchetes dentro de outra. O *parser* consegue separar corretamente ambas: a mais externa (`['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def'] + xyz]`) e a interna (`[abc + 'def']`).

Usando [a regex da outra resposta](https://ideone.com/6ZSzSz), a saída para o último caso é:

```
Captura: [aa]
Captura: ['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def']
```

Repare que ele pegou somente **parte da segunda expressão**, e a terceira foi ignorada.

> Claro, não foi dito que você tem casos assim, foi só para mostrar as limitações de se usar regex.

---

## Alterações na estrutura da expressão são mais simples do que com regex

Em uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/544032/112052) (que foi apagada) você quis adicionar o operador `*` nas expressões. Com regex fica bem complicado, pois só para entender onde mudar já é uma complicação.

Mas na solução acima, basta adicionar este operador na gramática (no arquivo `Expression.g4`). Na definição de `expr`, basta adicionar uma `multiplicativeExpr`:

```
expr
 : atom              #atomExpr
 | expr MULT expr    #multiplicativeExpr
 | expr PLUS expr    #additiveExpr
 ;
```

E mais abaixo, no lugar de:

```
PLUS : '+';
OPAR : '[';
```

Adicione a definição do operador `MULT`:

```
PLUS : '+';
MULT : '*';
OPAR : '[';
```

Depois basta gerar novamente as classes (`mvn clean install`) e testar com mais expressões:

```java
// no main
String[] entrada = {
    "1 + [aa]",
    "[bb] + 2",
    "'a' + [cc]",
    "['ola' + 'mundo']",
    "'[a' + 'b]'",
    "'[' + ']'",
    "[]",
    "'Ola [world] legal'",
    "Oi ['[aa]'] ola",
    "[aa] + 42 + ['bb' + 'cc' + [abc + 'def'] + xyz]",
    "[hello] + '' * [world]",
    "[a] + [b + 'c'] + ['abc' + 2 * '']"
};
for (String stringToVerify : entrada) {
    parse(stringToVerify);
}
```

Repare que adicionei mais duas expressões no final, com o operador `*`. Agora o *parser* passa a entender essas duas últimas expressões também:

```
Entrada: [hello] + '' * [world]
Captura: [hello]  |  [world]

Entrada: [a] + [b + 'c'] + ['abc' + 2 * '']
Captura: [a]  |  [b + 'c']  |  ['abc' + 2 * '']
```

A regex não funciona para a expressão `[hello] + '' * [world]`, pois ela só pega o `[hello]`.

Claro, até daria para mudar para algo como:

```java
String regex = "\\G"           // Início do texto ou fim do casamento anterior
    + "[^\\[']*"               // Texto sem colchetes nem aspas simples
    + "(?:'[^']*'[^\\['*]*)*"  // Opcional: Texto em aspas + texto sem "[" nem "'"
    + "[^']*"  // <-- *** AQUI ***
    + "(\\["                   // Grupo 1: Colchete de abertura
    + "[^]']*"                 //    + texto sem "]" nem "'"
    + "(?:'[^']*'[^]']*)*"     //    + texto em aspas + texto sem "]" nem "'"
    + "\\])";                  //    + colchete de fechamento
```

Pois agora ele pega zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas entre uma expressão e outra. Ainda é meio "simplista", pois falha em casos como `[hello] + '' * '' + [world]` (que o *parser* consegue analisar corretamente), e esse é o problema com regex: conforme as expressões vão ficando mais complexas, sempre pode aparecer um caso em que ela falha, já que ela está lidando com texto "bruto", sem analisar o contexto.

Isso é diferente do que o *parser* faz, pois ele analisa a estrutura e o contexto de cada parte da expressão, com base na definição da gramática (ele "sabe" quando é o conteúdo de uma string, ou um trecho de uma expressão, etc, coisa que a regex não faz). E para adicionar mais possibilidades, basta alterar a gramática (e se for o caso, o `ExpressionEvaluator`).

Por isso que, mesmo que haja uma curva de aprendizado para entender como definir a gramática e usar o Antlr, ainda sim acho que vale a pena, **por ser a ferramenta mais adequada para a tarefa**. Vale lembrar ainda que regex também tem uma curva de aprendizado que não é trivial para casos assim, e no final ainda não será a melhor solução, pelos motivos já citados.

Answer (score 1):

A regex abaixo vai capturar letras, números ou "_" que estão entre colchetes. Se você precisar de uma versão mais restritiva basta trocar "\w+" por [a-z]+, por exemplo.

```
\[(\w+)\]
```

Fiz um exemplo que você pode conferir:
http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96641

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas não resolveu meu problema por completo. Vou mostrar:  ['aa'] deve retornar ['aa'] mas '[aa]' não deve retornar nada.

Comment: Complementando, ['a'+'s'] deve retornar ['a'+'s'] ou 'a'+'s'